# Node editor is very slow when editing video

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I am using Blender to produce a 30 min. web cast weekly. Each episode includes multiple videos and still images that I composite primarily with the alpha-over node. I also use green screen, so there are a couple of keying nodes at play. This thirty min. web casts takes two full days to render. I have a top of the line AMD 8 core processor running with 8GB of ram and an 8gb video card. Can anyone suggest hardware upgrades or setting tweaks that may speed things up a bit?

Comment: A screenshot of your composite nodes would help. Do you include any 3d elements or just use blender's compositor? What render settings do you have. Are the source videos the same resolution as the final output?

Comment: Maybe blender is not the right app for this kind of work, specially if you are facing a deadline. There are a number of highly optimized video editors and compositors out there some you can use for free like resolve or fusion.